# Where is the input and output of this circuit?

Tags: diodes

I was instructed to put in a voltage probe at the input and the output of this circuit. Did I place the probes correctly?

[image]

Comment: Thought experiment: (1) What kind of circuit is this? (2) What do you think the input would be on this type of circuit? (3) What do you think would be the output on this type of circuit?

Comment: *Did I place the probes correctly?* If I place the probes on the points that I want to measure, how can they be incorrectly placed? It is **your** circuit so when the output isn't marked, even if **I** think that the output is at some point, that might be incorrect. Indicate what the output is, then probe there. Transistor's comment touches the issue: **what is this circuit supposed to do?** Or better: **what do YOU think it should do?**. Then what do **you** think are the input and output?

Comment: This is a bridge rectifier.

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is to understand what the circuit is for and how it works - Transistor is pointing in that direction. So you know its name ... what is it for and how does it work? When you can explain that, you will know where its inputs and output are.

Comment: The bridge rectifier is only 4 diodes in a bridge. I can use 4 diodes in a bridge as an RF mixer. Maybe your circuit isn't an RF mixer. I can also use 4 diodes in a bridge circuit to measure temperatures. "Bridge rectifier" describes the circuit, it doesn't explain its **function**.

Comment: A diode allows current to pass in one direction while blocking it in the opposite direction. A bridge rectifier converts AC to DC.

Comment: So, I take it that no one's gonna answer my question?

Comment: @JohnStewart Do you want to learn something? Then we're happy to assist: see the comments above. Do you want a free answer without doing effort yourself, then it is quite likely your last comment applies.

Comment: Study "bridge rectifier" and you'll find fast enough what's input and what's output. For (good drawn) schematics in general, there is an hint in the very first line of point 3 in the following answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/200815

Comment: @Huisman.                                                                                                           "Do you want a free answer without doing effort yourself?"                             
 What? You guys asked me to consider the purpose of the circuit. I did and still don't know the answer to the question and none of you guys have bothered trying to assist me beyond that. I can't learn anything if no one is willing to teach. Cut this "holier-than-thou" approach.

Comment: You are on the right track: *" A bridge rectifier converts AC to DC."*  So, what's the input of the bridge rectifier and what is the output?

Comment: I know the input is the ac source, still don't know where the output is supposed to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105414/discussion-between-huisman-and-john-stewart).